# Not applicable arguments to method setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, onclick

Whats wrong with my code? It doesn't work please help me!
Error message as follows:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View
>   is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})" And
>   another error message says "The method onClick(View) of type new
>   OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method

my code is as follows:

```
    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.m);

Comment: Just for your next question: Most people come to SO because *their code is not working*, so please choose another (more precise) title next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     }
```

to

```
      ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     }
```

and add the Activity in Manifest file

```
   <Activity
       android:name="package_name.Home">

     </Activity>
```

Comment: Sir @prakhar after trying the code that you've posted 1 error occured saying "Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener"

Comment: can you post the new code which you have copied from my answere this will help me to solve the problem..\